# Why is my dd slow when the blocksize is small?

Tags: linux, dd, xfs

According to articles on the web, mount with `nobarrier` will speed the disk up:

1. Write small blocks of data to img (with `barrier`): **SLOW**

   ```
   # dd if=/dev/zero of=xfs.img bs=1024 count=20000
   # mkfs.xfs xfs.img
   # mkdir -p xfs
   # mount -o loop xfs.img xfs
   # dd if=/dev/zero of=output bs=32K count=1 conv=fsync
   32768 bytes (33 kB) copied,0.01037167 s, 2.4 MB/s
   ```
2. Write small blocks of data to img (`-o nobarrier`): **FAST**

   ```
   # dd if=/dev/zero of=xfs.img bs=1024 count=20000
   # mkfs.xfs xfs.img
   # mkdir -p xfs
   # mount -o loop,nobarrier xfs.img xfs
   # cd xfs ; dd if=/dev/zero of=output bs=32K count=1 conv=fsync
   32768 bytes (33 kB) copied, 0.000608567 s, 53.8 MB/s
   ```

Now, I want to remount my `/` to add the `nobarrier` flag.
So I edited `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda2      /      xfs     defaults,nobarrier    0    0
```

then `mount -o remount /`.

But the result is not good:

```
# pwd
/root
# dd if=/dev/zero of=output bs=32K count=1 conv=fsync
32768 bytes (33 kB) copied, 0.00811443 s, 4.0 MB/s
```

I cannot understand why `nobarrier` is working for dd-img, but not working for existed partitions. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0):

When using a loopback filesystem, the filesystem it is created on must be taken into account. Specifically, the kernel will likely not be immediately flushing the written pages of the loopback FS to the containing filesystem's disk, despite fsync being called on the loopback fs. Those writes may be `sync`d on the loopback, but they may be sitting as dirty pages in memory for the containing FS.

Now, how the `nobarrier` option interacts with the loopback driver, as well as the containing filesystem, is something I'm not sure of. As such, I did an experiment. I added the variable of mounting the containing filesystem with `sync`. The results are as follows.

(all outputs from `dd if=/dev/zero of=xfs/output bs=32K count=10000 conv=fsync`)

1. containing fs `async`, loopback `barrier`

   ```
   32768000 bytes (33 MB) copied, 0.401873 s, 81.5 MB/s
   ```
2. containing fs `async`, loopback `nobarrier`

   ```
   32768000 bytes (33 MB) copied, 0.0414423 s, 791 MB/s
   ```
3. containing fs `sync`, loopback `barrier`

   ```
   32768000 bytes (33 MB) copied, 71.5749 s, 458 kB/s
   ```
4. containing fs `sync`, loopback `nobarrier`

   ```
   32768000 bytes (33 MB) copied, 70.6415 s, 464 kB/s
   ```

The `barrier` and `nobarrier` speeds vary heavily when the containing fs is `async`. However when the containing fs is `sync` and doesn't benefit from the page cache, the speedup mostly disappears.

The conclusion is that testing `barrier` and `nobarrier` with a loopback filesystem isn't going to be helpful. The containing filesystem's interaction with the kernel caching is going to get in the way. I suspect that the kernel cache is not the only thing which will cause erroneous results when testing performance using loopbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with such assumptions on Linux. Linux was optimized to create the impression of speed with respect to filesystems instead of optimizing the real speed.

The reason for getting the impression of high speed is that the file data (in many cases) is not on the disk when the writing program finishes. In other words, you cannot tell **what you metered** with your test as you do not know the filesystem state after dd finished.

If you like to get comparable results, you need to set up a performance test that is immune against the named problem, so you would need to write a file that is at least twice the size of your local RAM in the machine.

Comment: There are a few ways to get around the caching stuff which are preferable to using a file larger than RAM. Using dd with fsync, like the asker is doing, will cause an fsync which forces the write to disk after each write. Mounting a filesystem in `sync` mode will accomplish the same thing. Also, testing directly against a block device without a FS will avoid any caching layer. Alas, in the asker's case the loopback usage is going to throw results off.